# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL with simple servlet

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

i'm trying to solve this problem since 2 days, there are the same title of problems in many post on stackoverflow but it was all different, because they  allways had an error in code, but in my case i have a sample servlet, and when i run the project i get this error

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>    this is my class servlet

```
    package web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest requet, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
        out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>test2</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cs</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cs</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

please tell me how solve this problem, thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Simple doGet Servlet Or You Can add try catch blog to debug code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class logout extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        try
        {
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            out.println("Hello");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably have not add GAT method on form attribute Like this

```
<form action="web" method="GET"></form>
```

Comment: i don't have a form i want to write the url in the browser directly